# Contact management software for a hospital

Tags: database, information-management, contact-manager, collection-manager, address-book

I am looking for a phonebook software that can help organize how both internal and external telephone numbers are being handled in our hospital.

**Current situation**: Every ward/day clinic has their own separate Word or Excel file containing the telephone numbers they feel are most important for their daily operation. These are printed out and put up next to the phones, so that numbers can be found without logging into a PC first. However, information is outdated, layouts are inconsistent, and staff from other wards need to adapt to the new list before being able to use them effectively.

**Goal:**

- Have a database of names/functions ("radiologist on call after 18:00", "pharmacy - information", "pharmacy - chemotherapeutics") and numbers, managed by the administration

  - allow easy management/editing of said database
  - allow multiple names/function descriptions per number
- Allow each ward manager to select the names/numbers they need for their daily business
- Generate telephone directories for each ward, containing only the entries selected by the manager, that can be printed out
- In case of changes, only edit the database, then simply regenerate each wards telephone directory with the updated entries

**Requirements:**

- multiple names/function descriptions per number
- generate and save selections of numbers for each ward
- create nicely formatted telephone directories that can be printed out and put up around the ward for quick "offline" use
- Reasonably easy to use for average, non-technical users
- OS: Windows, or webapp running on a linux server

**Strongly preferred:**

- German localization / ability to translate the interface

**Nice to have:**

- Adapt styling of the generated telephone directories to our corporate identity
- online interface

Is there any software that might fulfill our needs?

Comment: Is this a multi user thing that will be potentially edited by many people? Or would you be the only editor/manager and then "distribute" the data read only to each ward?

Comment: Only a few people in administration would need editing/management rights, they would then distribute the data read-only to the wards.
Data would change very infrequently, so handling concurrent reading/writing by multiple users is not required.

Comment: While not a dedicated solution https://tiddlywiki.com/ is pretty flexible and scriptable with its tag based organization system. With a little elbow grease it may fulfill your requirements. Being browser based means it is both accessible to less technically inclined users, and very skinnable with standard CSS

Comment: Hi. Please I am interested in knowing the chosen solution. Thanks.